# Why Does Subscan Show Only 12M Blocks And Not Several 100M?

Tags: polkadot, block-production

By my calculations Polkadot should create 1 block every 6 seconds which is confirmed by looking at https://polkadot.subscan.io/ - however it states there are only 12M blocks when there should be many more blocks since launch date.

Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polkadot is running since roughly two years. If you take this into account:
`2 years * 365 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds / 6`

You will end up with `10512000`. So, not really several 100 millions.